# Alias shell command work inside container but not with docker exec "alias"

Tags: linux, docker, shell

To simplify test execution for several different container I want to create an alias to use the same command for every container.
For example for a backend container I want to be able to use `docker exec -t backend test` instead of `docker exec -t backend pytest test`

So I add this line in my `backend` Dockerfile :

```
RUN echo alias test="pytest /app/test" >> ~/.bashrc
```

But when I do `docker exec -t backend test` it doesn't work, otherwise it works when I do `docker exec -ti backend bash` then `test`.
I saw that it is because alias in `.bashrc` works only if we use interactive terminal.

How can I get around that?

Comment: You want `echo 'alias test="pytest /app/test"'`. Your quotes get removed..

Comment: Oh indeed, but I tried with `RUN echo 'alias test="pytest /app/test"' >> ~/.bashrc` and it doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

`docker exec` does not run the shell, so `.bashrc` is just never used.

Create an executable in `PATH`, most probably in `/usr/local/bin`. Note that `test` is a very basic shell command, use a different unique name.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks!
How can I create an executable in `PATH`? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

That alias will only work for interactive shells, if you want that alias to work on other programs:

```
RUN echo -e '#!/bin/bash\npytest /app/test' > /usr/bin/mypytest && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/mypytest
```

Comment: My container is run by root user so I tried this but it doesn't work:
`RUN echo -e '#!/bin/bash\npytest /app/test' > /usr/bin/root && \
  chmod +x /usr/bin/root`

Comment: do as my example and the command you need to run for the alias is mypytest

Comment: Oh ok my bad, I tried it but when I do `docker exec -t backend mytest` I have this error: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec format error: unknown`

Comment: get a bash shell inside de container and run mypytest

Comment: If I get a bash sell inside the container it will works even with just `RUN echo alias test="pytest /app/test" >> ~/.bashrc` but I want to be able to just run it with `docker exec -t backend test`

Comment: run it with: docker exec -t backend mypytest

Comment: Oh I did a typo, I tried `docker exec -t backend mytest` and it doesn't work

Comment: the command is called mypytest if you followed the example

Comment: Yes, my bad. I wasn't explicit. I named `mypytest` `mytest` and it doesn't work without using directly the bash in container